# Determine if the Set of Vector is a Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you help me check whether what I did is right or wrong?
Here are the questions:

> Which of the following sets are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$?
>
> **(a)** The plane of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that passes through (7,-3,2) and is
>   perpendicular to to the vector <1,1,-1>
>
> **(b)** The plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that passes through (2,1,3) and
>   perpendicular to the vector <1,1,-1>
>
> **(c)** The set of all vectors with in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with their tail at the
>   origin and their tip at the point on the curve $y = x^2$.

Here is my attempt:

**(a)** The equation of the plane is $1(x-7)+1(y+3)-1(z-2)= 0 \implies x+y-z-2 = 0 $.

The coordinates of the 0 vector are <0,0,0>. Therefore since 0+0-0-2 = 0 is impossible, **(a)** is not a subspace

**(b)** The equation of the plane is $1(x-2)+1(y-1)-(z-3)=0 \implies x+y-z = 0$.

Let the vector $u_1 = <1,-1,0>$ and $u_2 = <3,-3,0>$.

The coordinates of the zero vector <0,0,0> satisfy the equation of the plane
$u_1 + u_2 = <(1+3),(-1-3), (0+0)> = 0$.

$t(u_1) = t<1,-1,0> = 0$ and therefore **(b)** is a subspace.

Can you guys explain **(c)** to me and check whether **(a)** and **(b)** are correct?

Comment: a) is correct! If the vector $(0,0,0)$  is not in the plane, then it is not a subspace.

Comment: is b) correct and can you explain c) to me. thanks

Comment: You're right about b), but your answer is not a full proof. c) fails to be a subspace: try multiplying one of the vectors by a non-zero constant.

Answer (score 1):

To show that a set of vectors $V$ is a subspace of a vector space, it is sufficient and necessary to show that:

**1.** $0 \in V$
**2.** $V$ is closed under addition -- i.e. if $u,v \in V$, then $u+v\in V$.
**3.** $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication -- if $v \in V$ and $a$ is a scalar, then $av \in V$.

Your proof for **(a)** is correct, since you showed that **1.** does not hold.

For **(b)** you showed that **1.** holds. To show that **2.** and **3.** hold for **(b)**, find two vectors $u,v$ in the plane which are linearly independent, i.e. such that every point in the plane can be written as $t_1 u + t_2 v$ for some scalars $t_1, t_2$. As it stands, you have not given two such vectors yet.

For **(c)** find an example where either **2.** or **3.** fails to hold.

Comment: To correct point b) he only really needs to show that properties 2 and 3 hold for two generic vectors of the subspace, there's no need to find a base...

Comment: That's true -- I thought finding a base would be the easiest way to show that, but you're right that it is sufficient but not necessary. It was unclear to me what OP was trying to show after demonstrating property 1.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of preference. I hate non-standard bases, and always go for the arbitrary vectors approach. After all, it's not like I'll need to do any significant maths on that subspace...